# PHP MVC sessions

Tags: php, model-view-controller, session

Im trying to use the $_session variable in the model of the MVC to get the scores and names of the user logged in and then send it to the view through an array.

This is my game model. How would i get the SESSION variable from the view? When the user submits the loginform, the page goes to login.php which checks if the user exists, and if so start a session:  $_SESSION['username']=$_POST["username"]; If i set the username as "test" in the mySQL queryt it works.

```
public function game()
{
    include 'connect.php';

    //$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME='"$this->$_SESSION["username"]."'";      
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME='test'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $score = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

    $user = $score['username'];
    $s1 = $score['score1'];
    $s2 = $score['score2'];
    $s3 = $score['score3']; 

    //store values to array for view to see, extract() array so views can use 
    them as variables 
    $game_model = array('user' => $user, 's1' => $s1, 's2' => $s2, 's3' => $s3);
    return game $model;
}
```

Comment: As it stands right now, you are **wide open** to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: "How would i get the SESSION variable from the view" --- you shouldn't. View should  know nothing about any data storages

Comment: @Brad: well, it depends. There is a chance username is validated on registration process, thus nothing malicious there

Comment: So i should make Login.php a view and bind it with a model instead of just plain .php? How i then get the session variable to other functions within the model class?

Comment: @zerkms, In his question, he specifically states that he sets `$_SESSION['username']=$_POST["username"];`.

Comment: @Brad: oh, missed that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it in from the controller as an argument to the function.

```
public function game( $username )
```